# Is it possible to set start position when using eventhubtrigger?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to set the start position for my event-hub listener to the end of the stream.

I've been looking for a solution, but could not find any.

```cs
public static async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("x", Connection = "y", ConsumerGroup = "z")] EventData[] events, ILogger log)
{
    foreach (var eventData in events)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"{eventData.SystemProperties.EnqueuedTimeUtc}");
    }
}
```

host.json:

```
"extensions": {
    "eventHubs": {
        "batchCheckpointFrequency": 5,
        "eventProcessorOptions": {
            "maxBatchSize": 256,
            "prefetchCount": 512
        }
    }
},
```

Is there any setting I can set to force it to start at the end?

Edit: typo

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer after 1 day of searching. **NO** is the answer for now as far as I can tell from the thread.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1240